# Regex \\s* vs \\s+ After Lookbehind

Tags: regex

Is there some reason ++ works in a negative lookbehind while *+ does not?

Here's a MCV example:

```
select regexp_extract(
               'the hay   barn has cabins and hay.'
                , concat(
                '(?<!\\b(?:hay)\\b)'
                ,'\\s+'
                ,'('
                ,'\\b(?:antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\\b'
                ,')'
                ), 1),
                'the hay   barn has cabins and hay.'
```

For some reason in this case + is working but * is not?

Comment: You do not have any `++` in the lookbehind.

Comment: *+ does not work, but ++ does

Comment: @user48944 You don't have either of them in the lookbehind.

Comment: Are you sure? I doubt that. Prove.

Comment: So * is not in the lookbehind?

Comment: The lookbehind is `(?<!\\b(?:hay)\\b)`

Comment: I suppose you want `(?<!\bhay\s)\b(antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b`, but it will not work if there can be 2 or more spaces between `hay` and the alternations. If your engine were .NET, you could write `\s*` in the lookbehind.

Comment: Sorry yes. I should have stated this was outside the lookbehind. I am still unclear as to why the + works but not *.

Comment: It is because of backtracking.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Sorry I'm fairly new to regex.

Comment: What is the regex engine here? PCRE? Is it MariaDB?

Comment: It's in Hive / Tez. I believe Java.

Answer (score 1):

The [`(?<!\b(?:hay)\b)\s*(\b(?:antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/UU0Um4/1/) pattern matches `barn` in `the hay barn has barns with cottages and hay`.

That happens because of backtracking. The `(?<!\b(?:hay)\b)` lookbehind fails the match if there is a whole word `hay` before the current position, so, the position after the first `hay` is skipped and the regex engine goes on to check the position after the space. There is no whole word `hay` immediately to the left of that location, so the lookbehind returns *true*. The number of whitespaces can be then 0 (due to `*`), thus, the `\s*` succeeds, as does the rest of the subsequent subpatterns.

Note that using a lookbehind before a quantified subpattern is not useful. You might use [`(?<!\bhay\s)(\b(?:antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/UU0Um4/2) (note a non-quantified `\s` after `\bhay`), but it will fail if there are 2 or more whitespaces before the expected match.

A more tangible work around is to use a regex that will match the words you need in the context with `hay` and that will match and *capture* those words in all other contexts. Something like

```
\bhay\s*(?:antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b|\b(antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UU0Um4/3). All the matches you need will be in Group 1.

Comment: Why is it not useful? I am needing a solution that allows for >2 spaces as the text is freeform.

Comment: Well, there is a work around, and I added it. However, there may be empty values in the results (when the "unwanted" alternative matches). You will have to get rid of them using a bit of additional code. Another point is that `a\b\s*\bz` will require at least 1 whitespace between `a` and `z` for the match to occur, that is why I wrote `hay\s*(?:...)`, with no `\b` round `\s*`.

Comment: Any idea if the lookbehind or what you have proposed is faster? Nevermind, I see that this seems like the only solution if there is >1 space.

Comment: @user48944 I do not say it is faster. The `(?<!hay\s)` like version is just a logical contraction of the pattern since `(?<!\bhay)\s+` (if there are two whitespaces or more) and `(?<!\bhay)\s*` (your current scenario) will not work anyway. The last one is a common work around for such regex engines that do not support unknown width lookbehinds.

Comment: \b(?:hay|red|yellow)\s*(?:antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b|\b(antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b

Is this valid as well?

Comment: There problem I am seeing with \bhay\s*(?:antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b|\b(antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b

Is that if your first non-capture group matches then you won't capture anything else in the string. (for example hay barn doesn't match so everything else is skipped even though cabin should be matched).

Comment: @user48944 That one is good, too. After the first alternative matches, the string is not skipped, just Group 1 value is empty.

Comment: It does not seem to be matching for any of the capture groups.

Comment: Just to clarify, select regexp_extract(
               'the hay        barn has cabin and hay.'
                , concat(
                '('
,'\bhay\s*(?:antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b|\b(antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\b'
                ,')'), 1),
                'the hay       barn has cabin and hay.' 

Is not doing anything.

Comment: Well, if you have a look at it [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PI52e9/1), you will see that the matches you need are in Group 2, not Group 1. And note you might need to use double escapes in your code (I provided the patterns as literal strings)

Comment: Is there a way to do this for a general case? Suppose I do not know if the hay will be present or not and want to extract these words?

Comment: Also for select regexp_extract(
               'the hay        barn has cabin and hay.'
                , concat(
                 '(',
'\\bhay\\s*(?:antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)|\\b(antique|historic|bungalow|cabin|barn)\\b',')'), 2),
                'the hay       barn has cabin and hay.'


my query returns Null

Answer (score 0):

So one solution for this is to put a fixed width //s{0,x} in the negative lookbehind.

Comment: It is because the regex engine is Java, well, and it does support a constrained width lookbehind. It has its own gotchas, but may work for you in the current scenario. If the final lookbehind pattern is not too complex and the *max* part is not too high, it will work.